# Google Play Store on emulator stuck at "pending" when downloading or updating apps

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play, google-play-services

I'm trying to use Google Play Store on my Android emulator for testing purposes. However, I keep getting stuck at "pending" when downloading or updating apps.

I'm on the Apple M1 and launching the emulator from Android Studio.

[image]

Comment: Note: this issue isn't limited to Apple, whether the M1 chip or not.. @vin, you should check the answers below, all three are valid points to check, at least one of which should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yS9r.png)

I solved it by going into:

Emulator Settings > Network & Internet > Internet >
T-Mobile Settings[Gear Icon] > Changed the Preferred Network Type from 3G(default) to LTE (recommended)

Comment: Just for reference: with Android Emulator `31.3.13`, this option is found as "Network type" under the "Cellular" page of the running emulator's "Extended Controls" window.. and yes, this fixed it for me too. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the additional reference @AndreGreeff. And most welcome :)

Comment: This is solve the issue. @VIN can you marks this answer as accepted.

Comment: This solved my issue. Thanks!
I changed the emulator Network Type from "Full" to "LTE" 

Answer (score 3):

1. Check you Internet Connection https://fast.com/
2. Change you Internet Connection (e.g. from home/office router's Wi-Fi to Mobile 3G, 4G, 5G hotspot or vice versa, from Wi-Fi to wired Ethernet or vice versa)
3. Toggle Wi-Fi and Mobile data "ON"-"OFF"-"ON" in the emulator from
   Android Studio
4. Switch between Wi-Fi and Mobile data in the emulator from Android
   Studio
5. Clear cache AND/OR data for the app stucked in "pending" state
6. Clear Google Play Services app cache AND/OR data
7. Try to use different IP-address via VPN

https://www.techubber.com/how-to-fix-google-play-store-stuck-on-download-pending/

**Resolved OK for me in:**

```
Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server
VM by Oracle Corporation Windows 10 10.0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32312029)

Answer (score 2):

I've got that problem before. So, what I've done is switch off WiFi connection and allow Play Store to install and update application by using mobile data.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was in pending state, because Google Play services were upgrading in the background. Check the notifications at the top to make sure there are no in progress updates.